# HTML form element hidden onload javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Trying to get a HTML text input to be hidden on load, but then if a radio button is checked then the form will show.

http://pastie.org/private/ah39ul5h4jtmlntkbmmda

I've got it working sort of, I just need the field to be hidden on page load.

```
<form action="profile_edit_gravatar.php" method="post">
    <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" <?php if($row[16]=='account') {echo ' checked';}?> onload="this.form.otheremail.style.visibility='hidden';" onclick="
            if (this.checked) {
            this.form.otheremail.style.visibility='hidden';
            } else {
            this.form.otheremail.style.visibility='visible';
            }
            return true;
        ">
        Use <?php echo $row[3];?>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="otheremail">
</form>
```

Comment: why not just set the style with css?

Comment: because is should  be shown if row 16 is not account

Comment: then if row[16] == "account" give it a specific class or id and override the visibility in the stylesheet for that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about I give the radio and field an ID - actually less important now I wrote a script that use getElementsByName...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/MQD9Z/)

```
<?php $hide = $row[16]=='account'; ?>
<style>
<?php if ($hide) { echo '#otheremail {visibility:hidden;}'; ?>
</style>
<script>
 window.onload=function() {
   var rads = document.getElementsByName("gravatarradios");
   rads[0].onclick=rads[1].onclick=function() {
     this.form.otheremail.style.visibility=(this.value=="Use")?'hidden':'visible';
   }
   if (<?php echo $hide; ?>) rads[0].click(); else rads[1].click();
 }
 </script>
```

HTML

```
<form action="profile_edit_gravatar.php" method="post">
<label class="radio" for="gravatarradios1">
    <input type="radio" name="gravatarradios" id="gravatarradios1" value="Use">
    Use     </label>
<label class="radio" for="gravatarradios2">
    <input type="radio" name="gravatarradios" id="gravatarradios2" value="Use other">
    Use another email:
</label>
<input type="email" name="otheremail" id="otheremail" placeholder="Gravatar email address">
</form>
```

Comment: This would work, but needs to be live on the page. This is what I have so far: http://dev.jaycraft.co/player/gravatar.php

Comment: That would have been useful to see

Comment: Nope, must be a radio. The user is selecting whether they want to use their account email (from database), or a different email for their Gravatar.

Answer (score 0):

You can style it with CSS. This would hide all inputs by default:

```
input {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, still showed on load when I used input #otheremail {visibility: hidden;} and had the text input with id="otheremail"

Answer (score 0):

There is no onload event for input element, you can hide the element by default using CSS then work on it when the radio box clicked.

Another option is to use onload for body.

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].otheremail.style.visibility='hidden';" >
```

Comment: unless the PHP says it should be visible on load of the page

Comment: please do not use inline onload on body. It is overwritten so often